# PhpStorm add Angle brackets with tab

Tags: phpstorm

I start with PhpStorm but I don't understand why it adds angle bracket every time I press Tab.

In a html file (`|` cursor position) I type `a` then [Tab]. I get `<a href= "|" >< "></a>` I write `<a href="test[Tab]"></a>` I have `<a href="test">|</a>` and then if I write `<a href="test">this[Tab]</a>` I have `<a href="test"><this>|</this></a>`!

No matter where I write to an htlm file, I have this behavior! In a php file, it simply doesn't make a tab. I reset the settings by deleting file ~/Library/Preferences/PhpStrom2017.2. But it's always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get rid of this behaviour for HTML files you can do this.

```
Settings | Emmet | HTML | Enable XML/HTML Emmet
```

-- disable this option.

[image]